# How can I add take profit only after the order is executed in fxcmpy?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I have a trading algo written in python using fxcmpy.
I open the trade:

```
order = con.open_trade(symbol, is_buy=True,
                            is_in_pips=False,
                           amount=str(lots), time_in_force='GTC',
                           order_type='AtMarket')
```

And then I add the take profit:
`con.change_trade_stop_limit(id, is_in_pips=False, is_stop=False, rate=tp)`
I do this because I want the take profit to depend on the trade price. I used to assume that the open price would be the last ask price but this is not always the case so the order would be rejected for false take profit (It would be lower than the current bid price for long trades)
The problem is that the order often is executed after the `change_trade` is executed so no change is applied.

How can I tell it to wait until it is executed?